# Parsing JSON objects with special characters in HIVE

Tags: regex, json, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a json object:

`{
    "value": "foo \n"
}`

As hive delimits lines using `\n`, I tried to remove every occurrence of it in the json string.

```
SELECT
regexp_replace(get_json_object(jsonObject, $.value), '\n', 'bar'),
get_json_object(regexp_replace(jsonObject, '\n', 'bar'),$.value)         
FROM ...
```

returns: `foo bar, NULL`

Why is there a difference? Why does the second one return NULL? Intuitively, replacing the `\n` and extracting json makes more sense to me, but doesn't seem to agree with hive.

Comment: Are you sure you need to parse json?

Comment: I want to be able to extract the data in the json object.

Comment: Why don't you just change the delimiter on your table ?

Comment: I can. This is just a question of academic interest.